# How did St. Jerome defend the Blessed Virgin's virginity   in light of Matt. 1:25?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, virgin-mary, perpetual-virginity, virginity, jerome

How did St. Jerome defend the Blessed Virgin's virginity *post partum* in light of [Matt. 1:25](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=1&l=25-#x), which says St. Joseph "knew her not **till** she brought forth her firstborn son"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

St. Jerome proved that [Matt. 1:25](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=1&l=25-#x) neither affirms nor denies her virginity *post partum*.

St. Jerome wrote, in his commentary on Matthew, [*In Matth.*, I, 18](https://pld.chadwyck.com/all/fulltext?action=byid&id=Z300067279) ([*PL* 26](https://patristica.net/latina/#t026) [col. 24](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6MOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA23)):

> From the phrase ‘**before** [[έως](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%AD%CF%89%CF%82%20#lexicon)] they came together’ it does not follow that they came together afterwards; Holy Scripture merely intimates what did *not* happen [up until the time of Jesus's birth].
>
> <sup>Quod autem dicitur antequam convenirent, non sequitur quod postea convenerint, sed Scriptura, quod factum non sit, ostendit.</sup>

St. Jerome refutes this possibility by an example ([*ibid.*](https://pld.chadwyck.com/all/fulltext?action=byid&id=Z300067279)):

> If I say: ‘Helvidius died **before** he did penance for his sins,’ does it [necessarily/logically/always] follow that he did penance after his death?

and by citing other scriptural verses where doing (or not doing) something *until* a later time doesn't necessarily imply that one stops (or starts) doing it after said time:

> [Ps. 109:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=109&l=1-#x): “Sit thou at my right hand, **until** I make thy enemies thy footstool,” and [Gen. 8:6](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=8&l=6-#x) sq.: “… the raven … did not return **till** the waters were dried up upon the earth.” Does it follow, he asks, that Christ will no longer sit at the right hand of God the Father when His enemies lie defeated at His feet? Or did the raven return to the ark after the waters were dried up?

cf. [*Against Helvidius: The Perpetual Virginity of the Blessed Virgin Mary*](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3007.htm)

<sup>—Pohle-Preus, [*Mariology*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3789), pt. 2 ch. 1 §3 "Mary's Perpetual Virginity", "Thesis III: The Blessed Mary remained a virgin after the birth of her Divine Son"</sup>

<sup>(my **emphases**)</sup>

Comment: Let us see Mtt 1:25 in the context of biblical times when infertility was solely attributed to women . Mary proved her fertility by giving birth to Jesus . Absence of further children to the couple needed to be explained, lest the readers should take Joseph for an impotent man . And it was well known to those who witnessed the public life and death of Jesus, including how he entrusted the care of his mother to disciple John, that he had no sibling. So, Matthew chose to write about the life of abstinence that the couple had till the birth of Jesus, leaving the rest to the `as ye see it ' phase.

Comment: We use such phrases in day-to-day life eg. The outdoor stadium was packed for the finals, but the sky was heavily clouded. Everyone prayed that it may not rain. And lo, it did not, till the last whistle  !

Comment: @Kris "_it did not rain until the last whistle indicates that it never rained on those stadium grounds in perpetuity?_" No, you can't necessarily draw that conclusion. That's St. Jerome's point here: Matt. 1:25 neither proves nor disproves her virginity _post partum_.

Comment: Another example, from the Septuagint, of ἕως (heōs): So for Michal the daughter of Saul, she had no child until the day of her death (2 Samuel 6:23).

Comment: @ken The word in 2 Samuel is *'ad* not *heos* and is rendered unto not until.

Comment: Psalm 110:1 says unto, not until.  Genesis 8:6 does not say "...the raven … **did not return** till the waters were dried up upon the earth".  It says "And he sent forth a raven, **which went forth to and fro**, until the waters were dried up from off the earth. "  When the waters were dried up it stopped going to and fro.  That's what until means.

Comment: @PeterTurner I edited my deleted answer but didn't want to bullrush you by pasting the edits into a new answer.  Can you take a look and see if it makes the cut?

Comment: @MikeBorden - 'ad is the Hebrew in 2 Samuel. Heos is the Greek translation in the Septuagint, and is the same Greek word used by Matthew.

Comment: @ken Yes but "until" is not the best translation because there is no threshold indicated.  Michal's death is a hard stop as regards childbirth, that's why "unto" is better.

Comment: @MikeBorden - For those that knew Mary had only one child, his birth would have been a hard stop regarding childbirth, as well.

Comment: @ken If the Gospel writer had known such a thing "until" would not have been used.

Comment: @MikeBorden - I don't think we're on the same page. The Gospel writer didn't use the word "until." He used the Greek word "heōs." Translations are not inspired.

Comment: @ken What I'm saying is, in this verse, *heos* is best translated until.  I did not eat until I got home indicates that I did in fact eat.  If Joseph knew Mary not, ever, there is no sense to the phrase "until she had brought forth her firstborn son".  Until sets the limit on "knew her not".

Comment: And there's the obvious point that's being overlooked, why say "*firstborn son*" rather than "*only child*".

Comment: @RayButterworth Because firstborn sons have special legal status. There's no special legal status for only children.