# What are the main arguments Protestants use against the idea of the perpetual virginity of Mary?

Tags: protestantism, virgin-mary, perpetual-virginity, james-brother-of-jesus

Roman Catholics and Eastern Orthodoxy have the doctrine of the [perpetual virginity of Mary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_virginity_of_Mary). Protestants generally don't have that belief.

What are the main arguments Protestants use against the idea of the perpetual virginity of Mary?

This question is the opposite of [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-protestant-arguments-exist-for-the-perpetual-virginity-of-mary).

Answer (score 2):

They tend to be those of the heretic Helvidus, who held that:

- St. Mary had other children besides Jesus
- St. Joseph "knew her not till she brought forth her firstborn son" ([Matt. 1:25](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=1&l=25-#x)) means that he did know her after His birth

and thus she was not a perpetual virgin.

St. Jerome refutes these views in [*Against Helvidius: The Perpetual Virginity of the Blessed Virgin Mary*](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3007.htm) (383 A.D.) and [*In Matth.*, I, 18](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89085/1787).

Comment: Too bad Jerome didn't address Tertullian's points, but merely did what he condemned at point 24.  Oddly Jerome uses one argument of Tertullian's proof of a normal birth as a normal birth (no virginity remaining), but simply asserts a continued miracle as was the conception at point 20.  Perhaps so, but perhaps not.  Ah well,